# Pie Chart Not Showing Inside ScrollView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am creating pie chart in Scrollview which is the subview of the main view and then i am adding the pieChart as a subview of scroll view but it does not show pie chart

I have following code

```
   -(void)loadNews{

NSArray *graphs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", nil];

NSInteger numberofPages=[graphs count];


for (int i = 0; i < [graphs count]; i++) {

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    UIView*subView=[[UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subView];


    //PieClass *myPieClass=[[PieClass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250,450,320,230)];
    PieClass *myPieClass=[[PieClass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(327,470,320,230)];

    //myPieClass.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    myPieClass.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    myPieClass.itemArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:valueOne,valueTwo,valueThree,valueFour, nil];

    myPieClass.myColorArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIColor blueColor],[UIColor redColor],[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor brownColor], nil];

    myPieClass.radius=100;

    [subView addSubview:myPieClass];

}




self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * graphs.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
[pageControl setNumberOfPages:numberofPages];

[pageControl setActivePageColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:36/255.0 green:71/255.0 blue:113/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[pageControl setInactivePageColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CGRectMake(327,470,320,230)
You are setting the origin of 327,470

Try something like CGRectMake(100,100,320,230).

Comment: yes it is working now but same as i am doing for other chart it is not showing

Comment: >>"but same as i am doing for other chart it is not showing"<<____Would you elaborate please? Code snippet will be good so that I can see where is it going wrong...

Comment: mean i have another graph for Histograph with same co-ordinates i am giving but not showing

Comment: I'll need to see some of the code to find out what's going wrong. If it's okay then you can copy some.